# Different simple_form config for views from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I made a gem that uses simple_form and want to use a custom form builder so that my config doesn't interfere with the simple_form config of the remaining app. Sadly, I don't see how the SimpleForm.setup configuration can be for-this-builder-only. Do you have any idea how this can be achieved?